# USB issue SAM3S-EK -> Custom card

Tags: crystal-reports, usb, driver, atmel, sam

I am developing my project with SAM3S-EK demo board. I used USB CDC and MSC Driver with example code and ASF and everything work fine. Now I want to put the code into my custom card (with a SAM3S1B).
But that is my problem. I have assigned the pin and changed the clock config but the device is not recognized  by Windows. All of descriptors are equal to zero (according to USBLyser).

Can someone help me ?

That is my clock config file (I have a 16MHz crystal) :

```js
// ===== System Clock (MCK) Source Options
#define CONFIG_SYSCLK_SOURCE        SYSCLK_SRC_PLLACK

// ===== System Clock (MCK) Prescaler Options   (Fmck = Fsys / (SYSCLK_PRES))
#define CONFIG_SYSCLK_PRES          SYSCLK_PRES_4

// ===== PLL0 (A) Options   (Fpll = (Fclk * PLL_mul) / PLL_div)
// Use mul and div effective values here.
#define CONFIG_PLL0_SOURCE          PLL_SRC_MAINCK_XTAL
#define CONFIG_PLL0_MUL             32
#define CONFIG_PLL0_DIV             2

// ===== PLL1 (B) Options   (Fpll = (Fclk * PLL_mul) / PLL_div)
// Use mul and div effective values here.
#define CONFIG_PLL1_SOURCE          PLL_SRC_MAINCK_12M_RC
#define CONFIG_PLL1_MUL             16
#define CONFIG_PLL1_DIV             2

// ===== USB Clock Source Options   (Fusb = FpllX / USB_div)
// Use div effective value here.
//#define CONFIG_USBCLK_SOURCE        USBCLK_SRC_PLL0
#define CONFIG_USBCLK_SOURCE        USBCLK_SRC_PLL1
#define CONFIG_USBCLK_DIV           2

// ===== Target frequency (System clock)
// - XTAL frequency: 16MHz
// - System clock source: PLLA
// - System clock prescaler: 4 (divided by 4)
// - PLLA source: XTAL
// - PLLA output: XTAL * 32 / 3
// - System clock is: 16 * 32 / 4 / 2 = 64MHz
// ===== Target frequency (USB Clock)
// - USB clock source: PLLB
// - USB clock divider: 2 (divided by 2)
// - PLLB output: XTAL * 12 / 2
// - USB clock: 16 * 12 / 2 / 2 = 48MHz
```

Answer (score 0):

Like all USB devices used under Windows, you need to first install a Windows side USB driver that is specific to the device you are attaching.

When you install Atmel Studio 6.2 or newer, it installs a Windows side USB driver for the Atmel ASF USB driver you are using in your firmware. That Windows driver works with my SAM4E target processor. Be aware that it takes a long time to load the driver in Windows. It will appear to have hung. Just give it time, and it will eventually install the driver. You will probably have to respond to a pop-up warning to permit installation of an unsigned driver.

The Windows driver can also be downloaded and installed separately. Use this link:

https://gallery.atmel.com/Products/Details/6272a8fd-68fe-43d8-a990-741878cfe7b6?

Comment: Thank your for your answer. The problem is on the development card it works (I have the right driver) but on the custom card it doesn't work (the same code is running on equivalent architecture so I think I don't need new driver).

Answer (score 0):

Double check your clock rate. I am using the SAM4L part and it requires the PLL to run off of OSC0 to generate a 48 MHz clock. I had the same problem for a while because my ABDACB used the same clock and changed the rate. As I understand it, the plugging in of a USB device senses the single pull up resistor on the pin DP or DN depending on the speed. That is what tells windows (the host) to attempt to communicate. If the clock rate is wrong, the properties in windows all show 0s.